# Ruby: Reading from a file written to by the system process

Tags: ruby, file, io

I'm trying to open a tmpfile in the system $EDITOR, write to it, and then read in the output. I can get it to work, but I am wondering why calling file.read returns an empty string (when the file does have content)

Basically I'd like to know the correct way of reading the file once it has been written to.

```
require 'tempfile'

file = Tempfile.new("note")

system("$EDITOR #{file.path}")

file.rewind
puts file.read # this puts out an empty string "" .. why?

puts IO.read(file.path)  # this puts out the contents of the file
```

Yes, I will be running this in an ensure block to nuke the file once used ;)

I was running this on ruby 2.2.2 and using vim.

Comment: What version of ruby are you using, and what editor did you use to edit the contents.

Comment: I have commented - what difference do you think it makes?

Comment: It would make a difference if you were using something other than vim, because the call to `system` would exit before the editor itself does. My first guess was that you were trying to read the file before the editor had written in any bytes.

I think I've found your fix though, please see my answer below.

Comment: Hmmm, I tested this (on OSX) against nano and emacs too, and it did block until the file was written to... When I exited the program (vim/emacs/nano) after writing the file, the script displayed the results as I wanted.

Comment: Yeah, in a standard setup, most of the terminal-based text editors (vim, nano, emacs) will take over the entire terminal session, suspending the script. Editors that are stand-alone applications (sublime text, BBEdit, atom) would launch outside of the current terminal session, and the `system` call would return as soon as the application is launched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are calling `open` on the file object before attempting to read it in:

```
require 'tempfile'

file = Tempfile.new("note")

system("$EDITOR #{file.path}")

file.open
puts file.read
file.close
file.unlink
```

This will also let you avoid calling `rewind` on the file, since your process hasn't written any bytes to it at the time you open it.

I believe `IO.read` will always open the file for you, which is why it worked in that case. Whereas calling `.read` on an IO-like object does not always open the file for you.

Comment: Doh! yes, should have called open on it. Thanks! - and I'll have a play with the other system editors that osx is offering me (as I want it to work across at least the main ones). Thanks Steven!